# Recursively change the timestamps on all commits of a GIT repo

Tags: git

I want to write a simple script that would go over a git repo and change the timestamp of each commit  accordingly. Yet, I have no idea where to begin from. Any advice for a first step?

Answer (score 1):

The `git filter-branch` ([docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html)) command is designed to do tasks exactly like this.  The trick is figuring out what you want to change the timestamps to.

You can pass a filter to `git filter-branch` using `--commit-filter`, then modify the `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` environment variables.  Here is an example, which sets the commit date of all commits to January 1, 1970:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter 'GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=1970-01-01T12:34:56'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `git filter-branch`. It has a number of filters you can apply which can alter commits. Be warned that it's destructive and will rewrite the history of your project.